# I have a problem with a picturebox with animation gif, it is not move, by c# code

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a problem with a picturebox, I choose an image type of animation gif, The picture is displayed, but it is not move, by c# code

Comment: Do you happen to disable the PictureBox control? Post your code too please it should work in theory.

Comment: WinForms doesn't support animated GIF's

Answer (score 1):

this could help: [ImageAnimator.Animate Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imageanimator.animate.aspx)

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class animateImage : Form 
{

    //Create a Bitmpap Object.
    Bitmap animatedImage = new Bitmap("SampleAnimation.gif");
    bool currentlyAnimating = false;

    //This method begins the animation.
    public void AnimateImage() 
    {
        if (!currentlyAnimating) 
        {

            //Begin the animation only once.
            ImageAnimator.Animate(animatedImage, new EventHandler(this.OnFrameChanged));
            currentlyAnimating = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnFrameChanged(object o, EventArgs e) 
    {

        //Force a call to the Paint event handler.
        this.Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) 
    {

        //Begin the animation.
        AnimateImage();

        //Get the next frame ready for rendering.
        ImageAnimator.UpdateFrames();

        //Draw the next frame in the animation.
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(this.animatedImage, new Point(0, 0));
    }

    public static void Main() 
    {
        Application.Run(new animateImage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle the animation manualy. here's an example
http://www.vcskicks.com/csharp_animated_gif2.php

**Edit** code is available here: [Can a PictureBox show animated GIF in Windows Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485477/can-picture-box-show-animated-gif-in-vb-form)