# Put .Gif Image from Clipboard to PictureBox

Tags: c#, .net, clipboard, gif

I want to copy gif image from Browser and paste to PictureBox

```
 Image cImage = Clipboard.GetImage();
 pictureBox1.Image = (Image)cImage;
```

This put image, but its not animated.

Comment: Look at this answer, it's pretty concise. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13486374/72746

Answer (score 0):

The image on the clipboard isn't a GIF, it's a Bitmap or DIB (or both).  Those are the formats that you would see, if you used the old XP Clipboard Viewer (clipbrd.exe), or if you enumerated the available clipboard formats within your program.
See the list of standard clipboard formats: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729168(v=vs.85).aspx
GIF is not one of them.
Also, there is no JPG or PNG. When you copy those images, they're placed onto the clipboard as CF_BITMAP and/or CF_DIB.  Basically, Bitmap is the universal image format that everything converts to/from.

As an alternative, you MAY be able to get CF_HTML from the clipboard, figure out where the image is, and then fetch it from the server (or maybe the browser cache), preserving the original GIF information.

Comment: Somewhat related note: nowadays, type "PNG" _is_ used by multiple programs, to get around the lack of transparency support in the standard clipboard image format. It's just a png file byte stream with clipboard type identifier "PNG".