# Using animation in Picturebox

Tags: c#, animation, picturebox

Im working in 2D space invaders  game and i have done all the important part. Then, I decided to add some animation in the pictureBox to make my game look much better. My idea is to make the background picture as stars and i want to move this stars so it appears that my spaceship is actually moving.In different words, i want to make  the background picture moving and repeat it again and again.

i feel there is easy way to make, can help me please with key points to overcome this issue.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think this has sort of been answered already in how to use an animated gif for a `PictureBox`, in this case you'd have your stars moving as part of a gif.
[Link to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485477/can-a-picturebox-show-animated-gif-in-windows-application)

Although I wouldn't be surprised if it's a better approach to use some other control altogether rather than a `PictureBox`, but if that's what you're looking to use then hopefully my answer leads you to a solution.