# C# animated SplitContainer background image

Tags: c#, image, transparency, gif, splitcontainer

I want to make application where part of background must be animated.
I can't use picturebox, because i have to set transparent background in labels and "buttons" (changed picturebox).

When i set splitcontainer.backgroundimage to gif i can see no animated picture (in picturebox it works)

I'm begginer

Comment: Probably because `PictureBox` is coded to step through the animation, whereas the other(s) cannot.  If you want to do it manually, this post has useful methods:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485477/can-a-picturebox-show-animated-gif-in-windows-application

Comment: thanks for answer!
i have one problem...
could not find type or namespace: error is with FrameDimension

I have to add reference?

Comment: `System.Drawing.Imaging`